# Reducing apparent hair intersection

Tags: hair

I'm experimenting with ways to create realistic hair with much details as possible, however the first thing I face while I add more and more hair is the amount of intersection the hair starts to have:
[image]
[image]  ,
how do you reduce or avoid this in your hair grooms and hair simulations?